# how can I use double aggregation?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, nosql

I have the following problem .

I want to obtain the city with more incoming transport 
The schema is the following (origin:City)-[f:Transport]->(destiny:City)

Transport can be Bus,Plane,train

Right now I have this :

```
MATCH (origin:City)-->(destiny:Ciudad)
WITH Count(c) as incoming , destiny
return MAX(numero_de_entradas),destiny
```

The problem with this is that is that I am obtaining the same result as If I don't use MAX , I obtain results grouped by destiny , but I want to obtain the max of that ones.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you determine the counts per destination city, order them in descending order and return only the first one you will get the city with the most inbound transportation links.

```
MATCH (origin:City)-->(destiny:Ciudad)
WITH  destiny, count(*) as incoming
order by incoming desc
return destiny, incoming
limit 1
```

**Edit:** adding another option. This looks a little ugly but I think it holds water.  Collect the destiny and the number of inbound connections in a collection and get the maximum number of inbound connections.  Then unwind the collection of destiny nodes and their counts but only return the one(s) that match the **max_incoming** identifier. This seems like a lot more work than the first approach though. The advantage of this one though would be that if there were multiple cities that tied for the most inbound connections they would all be returned.

```
MATCH (origin:City)-->(destiny:City)
WITH destiny, count(*) as incoming
WITH collect([destiny, incoming]) as data, max(incoming) as max_incoming
UNWIND data as destiny
WITH destiny, max_incoming
WHERE destiny[1] = max_incoming
RETURN destiny[0], max_incoming
```

of course if you just needed to know the number you could simply return the max value from the matched rows.

```
MATCH (origin:City)-->(destiny:City)
WITH destiny, count(*) as incoming
RETURN max(incoming)
```

Comment: Thanks again jaja , but there will be other option to do it  instead of using your trick ?